# Replacing "\ + anyChar" with another string using REGEX

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a java application that finds all parts of a string that contain a backslash followed by any character "\ + anyChar" with another string. I am using am trying to use the regex patter "\." to look for a backslash followed by anyChar but it is literally looking for ".". What pattern can I use to look got backslash + anyChar?

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
  String input = GetInput();
  String regex = "\\.";
  String replacement = "[ ]"
  String result = input.replaceAll(regex, replacement);

  System.out.println("input:  " + input);
  System.out.println("result: " + result);
}
```

When I run this code I get the following to console

```
input:  this is some stuff and then should switch out this\stuff
result: this is some stuff and then should switch out this\stuff
```

Why is it that my regex pattern does not detect "\s" in this example?

Comment: You have to use 4 `\\`s to replace `\\`

Comment: At the moment you are replacing the dot and not the backslash

Comment: I tried setting regex to "\\\\." and it still did not work

Comment: well, its a forward slash in the input string....

Comment: your  regex should be  `"/."` since your input contain forward  slash only not backslash.

Comment: i see only forward slash in your input.

Comment: Ok. Do you need to replace forward slash or backward slash or both?

Comment: I used a poor example. I'll fix it. I need to only deal with backslash. I did not mean to use to forward slash in this example

Comment: All of the above... and a [DEMO](http://rextester.com/AOM88491)

Comment: It WORKED! Thanks Guys!